# Magento and Solr 3.6

Tags: java, php, search, solr

I struggle for weeks now using Solr (with Magento, it's why I have to use the 3.6 version) in order to separate compound German words.

For example, when a user type "herrenjacke" in the search engine, I want Solr to get documents with the words "herren" and "jacke", with an "AND" operator between them.

I tried to use the `DictionaryCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory` at query time, but the word "herrenjacke", "herren" and "jacke" are searched (I just want "herren" and "jacke") with the operator "OR" between them.

The perfect query would be:

```
("herrenjacke" OR("herren" AND "jacke"))
```

Same problem when I use the `HyphenationCompoundWordTokenFilterFactory`.

I tried as well to use a custom filter you can find here: https://github.com/wayfair/compound-splitter

Problem: impossible to compile the Java sources, there is some errors when I try to (I'm a PHP developer and Java is as mysterious as the Bermuda Triangle for me).

Comment: Can you let us know more specifics about what you did with the compound-splitter library and your problems compiling our Solr java stuff?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

You can see this issue, I have the same problem:

https://github.com/dweiss/compound-splitter/issues/2

Comment: Looks like there are still issues with the checked in version of the pom.xml in that project. :( Issue 2 was fixed, hopefully issue 3 is fixed soon!